# select option by containing text

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

```
<select class='selb' id='selbauth' >
```

this works:

```
$('#selbauth option[value="abc"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

the same but selecting not by value but by text - doesn't work:

```
$('#selbauth option[text="lorem"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

I tried another way:

```
function selbytext(dd, txt){
for (var i = 0; i < dd.options.length; i++) {
    if (dd.options[i].text == txt) {
        dd.selectedIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}}

selbytext($('#selbauth'), 'lorem');
```

error:
`Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/5rc49waj/

```js
$('#selbauth option:contains("abc")').attr('selected','selected');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='selb' id='selbauth' >
  <option>Test 1</option>
  <option>abc</option>
</select>
```

I've used `jQuery contains`.

**Reference Document:** https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/

If you are using jQuery version greater than 1.6 then use `prop` instead of `attr.

```
$('#selbauth option:contains("abc")').prop('selected','selected');
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @puerto Welcome buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

`text` is not an attribute. Use `:contains` to search the text contents of an element.

```
$("#selbauth option:contains(abc)").prop('selected', true);
```

Also see [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) for why I used `.prop` instead of `.attr`.

The reason your second code didn't work is because `dd` is a jQuery object, not a DOM element. It would have worked if you'd written.

```
selbytext($('#selbauth').get(0), 'lorem');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `contains` for achieving this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var selectText = 'Audi';
  $('#test option:contains('+selectText+')').attr('selected','selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='test'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use contains as @Shiladitya show you if the text you're searching can't be a substring of another option. If you need an exact match, you can use filter...

```
$('#selbauth option').filter(function () {
    return $(this).html() == "lorem"; 
}).attr('selected','selected');
```

I hope it helps